# How to create Horizontal MvxListView in Xamarin.Android using MVVM-Cross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have list of items those I need to display Horizontally with scroll.

I'm using Mvvm-Crosss, I created MvvmListView and added MvxItemTemplate for that Like below .

**MvxListView:**

```
 <MvxListView
            android:id="@+id/RelatedProductItems"
            app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/related_product_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CompleteExperienceLayout" />
```

**related_product_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/ProductImage"  
    android:layout_width="60dp"  
    android:layout_height="60dp"  
    android:scaleType="fitXY"  
    app:MvxBind="Bitmap StringToImage(ImageData)"  
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"  
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"  
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"  
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />  
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/ItemName"  
    android:layout_width="0dp"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:ellipsize="end"  
    android:textColor="@color/black"  
    android:textStyle="bold"  
    android:maxLines="2"  
    android:text="Product name"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"  
    app:MvxBind="Text Name"  
    android:textSize="18sp"  
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ProductImage"  
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ProductImage"  
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I Achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For items in a horizontal manner you need to use MvxRecyclerView (You have to install its nuget package)

Access Recycler View in your activity class and set its Layout Manager Horizontal

```
        MvxRecyclerView mvxRV = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.SampleRecyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal, false);
        mvxRV.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```